# react-google-login npm package error in version of react@"^18.2.0" from the root project

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, react-google-login

I'm getting error in `react-google-login` npm package here i've shown build code

```
10:50:18 AM: Build ready to start
10:50:21 AM: build-image version: 72a309a113b53ef075815b129953617827965e48 (focal)
10:50:21 AM: build-image tag: v4.8.2
10:50:21 AM: buildbot version: 515e5c33287d8b909c004fcf2e460e8645e8c1c6
10:50:21 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
10:50:21 AM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
10:50:21 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
10:50:21 AM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
10:50:21 AM: git clone https://github.com/abhidadhaniya23/xlinks-client
10:50:22 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
10:50:22 AM: Parsing package.json dependencies
10:50:23 AM: Starting build script
10:50:23 AM: Installing dependencies
10:50:23 AM: Python version set to 2.7
10:50:24 AM: v16.15.1 is already installed.
10:50:25 AM: Now using node v16.15.1 (npm v8.11.0)
10:50:25 AM: Started restoring cached build plugins
10:50:25 AM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
10:50:25 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
10:50:26 AM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
10:50:26 AM: Using PHP version 8.0
10:50:27 AM: No npm workspaces detected
10:50:27 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
10:50:27 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
10:50:27 AM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 8.11.0
10:50:27 AM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
10:50:27 AM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
10:50:27 AM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
10:50:28 AM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
10:50:28 AM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
10:50:28 AM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR!
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR! While resolving: react-google-login@5.2.2
10:50:30 AM: Creating deploy upload records
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.3.0
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
10:50:30 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.3.0" from the root project
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR!   2 more (react-dom, react-scripts)
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR!
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR! peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react-google-login
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR!   react-google-login@"^5.2.2" from the root project
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR!
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR!   peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR!   node_modules/react-google-login
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR!     react-google-login@"^5.2.2" from the root project
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR!
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR!
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR! See /opt/buildhome/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
10:50:30 AM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2022-07-01T05_20_28_238Z-debug-0.log
10:50:30 AM: Error during NPM install
10:50:30 AM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
10:50:30 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
10:50:30 AM: Finished processing build request in 9.18683257s
```

I've also tried `npm install react-google-login --legacy-peer-deps` command to install react-google-login but still build failed in netlify building process.
This log, I've atteched from netlify build.

When I install packages using `npm install` it shows `6 high severity vulnerabilities`

Comment: which node version are you using now? and once try clearing caching

Comment: I'm using 16.15.1 node version